# Create an ajax call to auto complete a search in semantic ui

Tags: ajax, semantic-ui

I'm trying to make a search with auto complete but its not working my js code is:

```
$('.ui.search')
    .search({
     debug: true,
      apiSettings: {
        action:'search',
        url: '/chat/addamigo/cod/{query}'
      },
    })
  ;
```

the return of the call is:

```
[{"title":"taaaaaalles","description":"552eecea80bc7be41a00002d"}]
```

and the html is:

```
<div class="ui search">
                    <input class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="... etc" >
                    <div class="results"></div>
                </div>
```

but it keeps showing me the blank message

"No Results
Your search returned no results"

what can i do to create an ajax auto complete in semantic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right sintax of the json that needs to be returned in the server-side is:

```
{
  "results": [
    {"title":"taaaaaalles","description":"552eecea80bc7be41a00002d"}
  ]
}
```